# R: print multiple types of plots on one page

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, venn-diagram

I am trying to plot multiple plots in one page. I know functions like `gridExtra::grid.arrange` that can plot graphs generated by `ggplot2` package. The problem I am facing is that I have two plots (`bar.plot` and `density.plot` below) that are generated by `ggplot2` package and one plot generated using `limma::vennDiagram` function. I have tried the below but it is not working:

```
output <- paste('summary.pdf')
pdf(output,width = 25,height = 20)
par(mfrow = c(3, 3))
plot(bar.plot)
plot(density.plot)
print(vennDiagram(dat.venn, circle.col = col,cex = c(3,3,3)))
invisible(dev.off())
```

dat.venn is a data of type VennCounts:

```
 I-H-10003-T1-D1 I-H-10003-T2-D1 I-H-10003-T3-D1 Counts
               0               0               0      0
               0               0               1     41
               0               1               0     81
               0               1               1     66
               1               0               0     10
               1               0               1      2
               1               1               0      4
               1               1               1     56
attr(,"class")
[1] "VennCounts"
```

I am unable to find a venn diagram package that is compatible with the `grid.arrange` function. I don't think that `VennCounts` cant be printed out with `grid.arrange` function and `ggplot2` plots can be printed out with `par` function.

UPDATE: 
I tried using pushViewport but it is still printing the venn diagram on the next page:

```
pdf(output,width = 25,height = 20)

# Create layout : nrow = 2, ncol = 2
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))

# A helper function to define a region on the layout
define_region <- function(row, col){
  viewport(layout.pos.row = row, layout.pos.col = col)
} 

# Arrange the plots
print(bar.plot, vp = define_region(1, 1:2))
print(density.plot, vp = define_region(2, 1))
print(vennDiagram(dat.venn, circle.col = col,cex = c(3,3,3)), vp = define_region(2, 2))
dev.off()
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/vignettes/gridBase.pdf

Comment: @Roland See my update

Comment: I don't see where you use functions from the gridBase package there.

Comment: The link that you gave me is a manual for gridBase. I saw there were some suggestions using `pushViewport` and I used it.

Comment: The suggestions are more specific than that.

Comment: Having needed to combine a mixture of plot types (grid-based and otherwise such as Excel, plotrix, etc.) I have saved them all as. .png files, used the read.PNG function of the grid package to load them, and then converted them with the rasterGrob function.  Once all the plots are comparable in format, grid.arrange() does the trick.

Comment: @lawyeR Thank you very much! This worked!! Can you move your comment to an answer so I can accept it? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, save each of the files as .png files, such as `save(yourfile, file = "yourname.png")`.

Second, use the read.PNG function of the grid package to load them, such as `yours.png <- readPNG("yourfile.PNG")`

After that, convert them with the rasterGrob function as in `g1 <- rasterGrob(yours.png, interpolate=TRUE)`.

Once all the plots are comparable in format, `grid.arrange()` does the trick.  It might look like this:

```
grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, nrow=1)  # one row
dev.copy(png,'threeplots.png')   # to save the array of plots     
dev.off()                         # to close the device
```

Answer (score 2):

The `gridGraphics` package, like `gridBase`, makes the mixing of grid, ggplot, lattice and base graphics fairly straightforward. The `grid.echo()` function converts a base graphic into a grid graphic. (The advantage of using `gridGraphics` is that base graphics become amenable to editing and modification via `grid`; see [gridGraphics.pdf](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/gridGraphics/gridGraphics.pdf).)

In the following, I draw two ggplots and a venn diagram (taken for the `vennDiagram` help page in the `limma` package), and I position the three plots within viewports, making sure the venn diagram plot is subjected to the `grid.echo` treatment.

**UPDATE to `ggplot2` 2.0.0**  (Default `stat` for `geom_bar` is `stat = "count"`)

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridGraphics)
  library(grid)
  library(limma)  # From bioC software repository

  grid.newpage()

  # Position 1st ggplot
  pushViewport(viewport(y = 1, height = 1/3, just = "top"))
  gg1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_density()  
  print(gg1, newpage = FALSE)
  upViewport()

  # Position 2nd ggplot
  pushViewport(viewport(y = .5, height = 1/3, just = "centre"))
  gg2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(carb, levels = 1:8))) + 
          geom_bar() + scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
  print(gg2, newpage = FALSE)
  upViewport()

  # Function to draw venn diagram - the venn diagram is taken from ?vennDiagram
  plotfun <- function() {   
   Y <- matrix(rnorm(100*6),100,6)
   Y[1:10,3:4] <- Y[1:10,3:4]+3
   Y[1:20,5:6] <- Y[1:20,5:6]+3
   design <- cbind(1,c(0,0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,0,0,1,1))
   fit <- eBayes(lmFit(Y,design))
   results <- decideTests(fit)
   a <- vennCounts(results)
   print(a)
   mfrow.old <- par()$mfrow
   par(mfrow=c(1,2))
   vennDiagram(a)
   vennDiagram(results, 
       include=c("up", "down"),
       counts.col=c("red", "blue"),
       circle.col = c("red", "blue", "green3"))
  }

  # Position the venn diagram
  pushViewport(viewport(y = 0, height = 1/3, just = "bottom"))
  grid.echo(plotfun, newpage = FALSE)
  upViewport(0)
```

[image]